# how do processor and RAM synchronize?

Tags: memory, x86, cpu-architecture, processor

For example, if my ram memory runs at 1333MHz and my processor runs at 4GHz, how can the memory controller (situated in the processor) send commands (active, read, write, etc.) to RAM memory if they both are running at different speed?

Comment: With some buffering of messages at the boundary between clock domains, especially if the clocks aren't a fixed ratio from each other.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_domain_crossing).  Also a more technical google hit:
 https://zipcpu.com/blog/2017/10/20/cdc.html.  Did you google this at all?  The memory controller runs at memory speed and handles communication with the rest of the CPU.  You have the same problem in a many-core Xeon where each core can run at a different frequency, unlike Intel's "client" chips where all cores share a clock (but some cores can be halted).

Comment: This is one of the main reasons that modern CPUs have caches. The CPU talks to the cache and the memory controller talks to the cache.

Comment: So, the memory controller in my example is running at 1333MHz (not at 4GHz), isn't it? and in the comunication between cache and memory controller is when the clock domain crossing "has to be done", correct? @PeterCordes

Comment: and what did you mean about "clocks aren't a fixed ratio from each other"?

Comment: A fixed ratio like 3:2 or 4:1 can be handled without really buffering, still synchronous, just a wider bus on the slower side.  But if the clocks aren't locked to each other, you need some kind of buffer / queue that one side reads, the other side writes, with the timing of their clock edges possibly varying.  This is why buffering between async clock domains adds more latency.

Comment: Thank you! And sorry for repeating myself but I just wrote two messages in a row (since I don't know if I can edit them) and you didn't get to see the first one, which said: So, the memory controller in my example is running at 1333MHz (not at 4GHz), isn't it? and in the comunication between cache and memory controller is when the clock domain crossing "has to be done", correct? @PeterCordes

Comment: BTW if that's DDR3 RAM (likely), then 1333MHz is the transfer speed, but the bus speed is 666MHz and the clock the actual module itself runs on is just 166MHz (using SerDes to reach the higher transfer speed, I guess?). So it's even more complicated than this question already asks about.

Comment: You can edit comments for up to 5 minutes.  And yes,I did already say that the memory controller runs at memory speed, I didn't feel the need to repeat myself.  So yes, obviously a boundary between clock domains exists somewhere. Either inside the memory controller (maybe running some of the buffering logic / read vs. write prioritization at uncore speed) or between the the memory controller and the ring bus.  (Or if not a ring bus, other interconnect between cores, system agent, etc.)

Comment: @PeterCordes - I didn't fully get your comment about client vs xeons. There is the uncore in the middle between cores and memory which is a separate clock domain. So client chips have to do a domain crossing to uncore to share data among themselves, as would xeons, regardless of the fact that xeon chips also have per-core DVFS... at least that's how I think it works.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Oops, you're right. https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/skylake_(client)#Clock_domains says there's a separate clock domain for the ring (uncore).  That sounds slightly familiar from BIOS tuning options, too.  I think the ring normally scales its clock to be similar to the cores (or at least not greater), so L3 performance does scale with core clocks.  (e.g. downclocking on memory-bound workloads with HW P-state with EPP != performance makes memory performance worse as well.)

Comment: @PeterCordes - IIRC there are scenarios where the uncore clock can be very high but the core clock low, but I don't have any details. At least that what's Intel suggests is a good idea especially when the power or thermal budget means running "both at max" isn't an option. For whatever reason `uncore_cbox_0/clockticks/` seems bugged on my system, always reporting way too small values, so I wasn't able to test.

Comment: I think it's important because the uncore clock is like this hidden thing that doesn't get much notice but is important for many benchmarks. Everyone knows about variable CPU frequency and handles or at least reports it, and memory frequency is always fixed, but uncore is this big important domain right in the middle that is rarely reported.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Dr. Bandwidth reports that *Xeon* systems of Haswell and later can keep the uncore high even if no cores are at high clocks; this is important for keeping up with snoops from another socket.  https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/543513.  IDK if there's any similar capability for client chips.  Earlier Xeons (like SnB-xeon) could do badly in single-core benchmarks when the other socket clocks down its L3.

Comment: @PeterCordes - right, but here I was thinking of a single-socket scenario, where uncore frequency is high but CPU frequency is low. Not sure if it actually happens though. Now I'm trying to figure out what's up with `perf` and uncore clock cycles.